# EWS Managed API: session is not IMailboxSession on Copy Item

Tags: api, exception, copy, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

we are using EWS Managed API to process items in our exchange public folders. We are able to traverse through folders, retrieve new items and change them. It is possible to Move an item to a specific folder but when we use copy method strange exception occurs: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., IdAndSession.MailboxSession: session is not IMailboxSession

To exclude a code issue I use an example provided by microsoft:

```
// As a best practice, limit the properties returned by the Bind method to only those that are required.
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.ParentFolderId);
// Bind to the existing item by using the ItemId.
// This method call results in a GetItem call to EWS.
EmailMessage originalMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, ItemId, propSet);
// Copy the orignal message into another folder in the mailbox and store the returned item.
Item item = originalMessage.Copy("epQ/3AAA=");
// Check that the item was copied by binding to the copied email message 
// and retrieving the new ParentFolderId.
// This method call results in a GetItem call to EWS.
EmailMessage copiedMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, propSet);
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange#copy-an-email-message-by-using-ews)
But the exception still occurs. Is it possible that this is a bug in Framework?
Thanks in advance for any help.